# Where to put software version for WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a new WPF project and I'm going to label the version as `1.0.0`, but on **Properties** it only says **Assembly Name**, **Default Namespace**, **Target Framework**. but no **Version**. Where can I find this? (Along with the project name, description, contributors, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are close, it is under your Project Properties--> Application tab  --> Assembly Properties button.

[image]

Comment: Got it!, Btw the versioning have 4 numbers, but I'm used to the **Version: `major`.`minor`.`revision`** schema, what's the 4th one for?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.revision(v=vs.110).aspx.  It's actually Major.Minor.Build.Revision.

Comment: The revision is the odd man out. The first three are used to determine if the file gets replaced during upgrades.

Comment: This button no longer exists (atleast on Visual Studio 2019 WPF application)

Comment: @Anil  I just created a new  WPF project in VS2019 to verify your comment. The button is stilll there it is called Assembly Information and is in the Application section.

Comment: Assembly Version and Assembly File Version are now at the bottom of the Package tab.

Comment: Yes, as @JosvanEgmond said,  it's renamed with "Package Version" now.

Answer (score 8):

There is an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in your project. (under `Properties` folder).

There are two attributes there, you can use them.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

To keep the versions aligned for all the projects in your solution you can have one `CommonAssemblyInfo` file and [link it to every project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/04/03/shared-assembly-info-in-visual-studio-projects.aspx).

Comment: I really dislike sharing assembly info files. I have one big project (forked from SharpDevelop) which does that, and whenever I update a single file, the assembly version for the entire project changes which breaks the upgrade system. Sharing for common properties is fine, but for versions, I would avoid it.

Comment: Sure @RonBeyer whatever works for you. In our case every commit triggers a build and deployment with a new version number. We want to have all binaries having the same version. So common file makes sense for us.